# Best way to get distro version in CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I usually do like below to check the rosdistro.
Are there better way to do like this?

```
# check ros distro >= indigo
execute_process(
  COMMAND python -c "import sys; sys.exit(ord('$ENV{ROS_DISTRO}'[0]) >= ord('indigo'[0]))"
  RESULT_VARIABLE DISTRO_GE_INDIGO
)
if(DISTRO_GE_INDIGO)
...
endif()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222608/best-way-to-get-distro-version-in-cmakelists.txt?/) by [wkentaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20444/wkentaro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 175 on 2015-12-16

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-12-16**:
I'm not sure whether there is a CMake macro defined anywhere. An alternative to the python one-liner might be to use `rosversion -d`. That returns `hydro`, `indigo`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a better solution by comparing $ENV{ROS_DISTRO} value with STRGREATER like below:

```
if("$ENV{ROS_DISTRO}" STRGREATER "hydro")
...
endif()
```

---

Originally posted by [wkentaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20444/wkentaro/) with karma: 175 on 2016-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can access the environment variable `ROS_DISTRO` directly in CMake:

```
$ENV{ROS_DISTRO}
```

Regarding the greater check: your approach makes assumptions about future releases which might not be true. Therefore I would suggest a more defensive approach comparing the distro name against a list of known names and inverting the logic.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-02-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2